# ogr2ogr: symbol lookup error: ogr2ogr: undefined symbol: _ZNK17GDALDriverManager14GetDriverCountEv

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import a ShapeFile inside my PostGIS database using the ogr2ogr, however I'm receiving an error:

> ogr2ogr: symbol lookup error: ogr2ogr: undefined symbol:
>   _ZNK17GDALDriverManager14GetDriverCountEv

The command that I'm using is that:

> ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1
>   dbname=DATABASE_NAME user=USER_NAME password=PASSWORD" points.shp
>   -skipfailures

I'm looking for it in Google, but without success.

Would anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Most probably a dependent DLL or SO was missing. It would be helpful if you can tell what OS you are using, how you obtained/install/built the GDAL/OGR tools, and etc.

Comment: I use the Ubuntu 16 and I had installed the GDAL/OGR by apt-get. Anyway, I resolved my problem purging and installing the libgdal20 again. I explained the steps below. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem was in the libgdal20 library, which it had the driver dependency: _ZNK17GDALDriverManager14GetDriverCountEv

Then I had to use a purge in this library and install everything again related to GDAL/OGR. Finally the OGR has started to work.

The following commands solved my problem:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt purge libgdal20
>
> sudo apt-get install libgdal20
>
> sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal postgis

Comment: thanks, you saved my day